# Magento 2 Homepage 404 Error

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404, magento2

This one is driving me crazy. The content section on my home page is returning 404, "Whoops our bad...".  I've tried everything I could find but nothing is working. I've tried all of the steps for the single-store mode bug. That didn't fix it. My "Default Web URL" is set to cms and I have my home page selected as "CMS Homepage." If I browse directly to the CMS page it works fine, but when I view my homepage, I get the 404....

I'm running Magento version 2.1.11.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

FIXED! - There was a row in the url_rewrite table with an empty request_path value. I deleted that row, refreshed the caches and it's working again!

Comment: Another case is Full page cache can’t distinguish GET request from HEAD request. If you do not have cached data or it is invalidated and web crawler send HEAD type request to your site, magento return 404 page and cache it. More here - https://nwdthemes.com/2019/06/28/magento-2-homepage-404-error/

Comment: Thank you had the exact same problem. :)